React Native running app on real android device. App not opening - (Samsung Galaxy A15)
I am trying to run a React native app on a real android device (Samsung Galaxy A15). I run  react-native run-android in my terminal. The app builds on the device but does not open. The device is listed, when I run adb devices and I have runned the command adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 which will forward the phone's 8081 port to the computer's 8081, where the packager listens. I also have switched on the developer options on the android device and the USB-Debugging option. When I run the app with the  --variant=release flag it works as expected. I have a USB-C cable which definetly is capable of transferring data. I have used a different android phone in the past and it worked with the same macbook. Anybody has any hint how to debug this issue?
System:
    OS: macOS 14.5
    CPU: (12) arm64 Apple M2 Pro
    Memory: 69.98 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.20.2 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.21 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 8.19.4 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2024.01.22.00 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.12.0 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 23.5, iOS 17.5, macOS 14.5, tvOS 17.5, visionOS 1.2, watchOS 10.5
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Electric Eel 2022.1.1 Patch 1 Electric Eel 2022.1.1 Patch 1
    Xcode: 15.4/15F31d - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: javac 15 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: 5.0.1-alpha.2 => 5.0.1-alpha.2 
    react: 18.0.0-rc.0 => 18.0.0-rc.0 
    react-native: 0.65.3 => 0.65.3 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found

Opening the android app on the real android device and working as expected.
